# wysiwyg or rich text in kivy python

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, wysiwyg, kivy-language

so i'm new to kivy and i have kachground from the web dev, and i have to create a rich text.

so i want any idées or solutions or librarys or steps on how to do that in kivy.

my probleme is that i don't know how to select a texte and make changes on it(change his size or it's color ...etc).

as a final result i want somthing like this

[image]

Comment: The [Label Widget](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html#markup-text) provides some support for text markup. You may be able extend `Label` to what you want, but it is not a simple project.